# Orthogonal Diagonalization and Non-Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, gram-schmidt

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable where, $A$ is non-symmetric i.e. $A^T\not= A$

And let $S = \{ \vec{v}_1 \,,\, \ldots \,,\, \vec{v}_n\}$  the set of the eigenvectors of $A$ , ($S$ is not orthogonal)

I understand that $A$ isn't orthogonally diagonalizable since it's not symmetric.

But another equivalent statement about the conditions of orthogonal diagonalization, is that the set of the eigenvectors of $A$ has to be orthonormal.

Hence, $$ A \text{ is symmetric } \Longleftrightarrow S \text{ is orthonormal} $$

But what if we apply Gram-Schmidt to $S$ to get a new orthonormal set $S'$ doesn't this allow $A$ to be orthogonally diagonalizable, even though $A$ was not symmetric, to begin with?

I tried to understand the flaw in this line of reasoning and, the conclusion that I landed on is that, it may have to do with the fact that the Gram-Schmidt process knocks every vector from $S$ off their span -except the initial vector $\vec{v}_k = \vec{u}_1$- to the span of the orthonormal component of its projection over the vectors before it.

Meaning, the Gram-Schmidt preserved the total span of $S$ but, not necessarily the span of each vector in $S$, 
then $S'$ is a different set in this sense and, no longer represents the eigenvectors of $A$.

Hence, $A$ is still not orthogonally diagonalizable.

I'd love to know if I'm close to the right answer or missing something.

Comment: You have presented a proof of a statement which you know to be false, and have looked in the proof a part where you probably implicitly assumed something that is false and believe you found one. What else are you looking for? You just proved that your proof is not convincing, since it doesn’t convince you. So, I guess the story is over.

Comment: I understand maybe the way I've put it was confusing, my apologies for that. The thing is, I was discussing this earlier with my instructor and he knew there was something wrong with this assumption, but couldn't figure what exactly at first. So, later I came up with the explanation above. And, I wanted to confirm that I wasn't missing something in my argument. In other words proofing to my argument.

Comment: I didn’t mean to sound bad, or severe, you don’t have to apologize. Let me rephrase my comment: the process of, when presented a proof whose conclusion looks false, find a part of the argument that is false, is the very nature of science. Your process shows that you have been a good scientist on this point, and that’s it! There is no obligation to « spot a mistake » if a proof isn’t precise; in that case, it is up to the person who wrote the proof to make it more precise.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the insight.  I do see your point. And it's true that, once the logic behind the proof is sound, that's what ultimately matters in terms of being true or false.